# pdf url not called shouldOverrideUrlLoading on android 4.4 webview but working on android 4.3 and below

Tags: java, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

Below code written inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` working on android 4.3 and below.  but not working on android 4.4 (Kitkat). while debugging I found `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` not called when I clicked on pdf link, but called on every link that not contain file.

```
if(url.contains(".pdf")){
    try{        
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent();
    browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(browserIntent);   
    }catch(){
    }
```

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 21. See  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Comment: Is there Any way to run this code on android 4.4